# Rails Form Check Box or select Array value for multiple arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, forms, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm maintaining a Rails 3.2.22.5 legacy app and creating a form to send messages internally to users (in this case they are called medics).  Here is what my form currently looks like.

```
<%= form_for(@mass_message, url: '/mass_messaging', method: 'post') do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :subject, placeholder: "Subject" %>
  <%= f.text_area :body, placeholder: "Body of message"%>
  <%= f.label :medic %>
  <%= f.select(:medic_ids, medic_select,  {}, {:multiple => true, :class => 'select'}) %>
  <%= f.button "Submit" %>

<% end %>
```

This works fine but I'd like to be able to shovel groups of Medics by a `division` column into the `medic_ids` array on the object.

From the console when I do the following:

```
m = MassMessage.new
m.medic_ids = Medic.where(division: "Dallas").map {|medic| medic.id}
m.save
```

It will get the ids that are mapped from the where clause and inject them into the `medic_ids` array properly and create the record in a join table called `MassMessageMedic` properly.

However, in this form I need the ability to create some sort of selector or even checkboxes in the form to select the different divisions of which there are 4.  So this is a two part question really

1.) Given these four statements (divisions)

```
Medic.where(division: "Dallas").map {|medic| medic.id}
Medic.where(division: "Houston").map {|medic| medic.id}
Medic.where(division: "Beaumont").map {|medic| medic.id}
Medic.where(division: "Texoma").map {|medic| medic.id}
```

How can I construct these into some sort of helper method that would allow each array to be selected (one or multiple) and injected into the `medic_ids` array?  I'm trying different things and thinking a helper method called `medic_select` might be the answer but I'm hitting a wall with how to create this selector which will essentially be an array of arrays if I'm not mistaken.

2.) Given the above arrays how could I instead of a selector in the form use a `check_box` to define that when the checkbox is clicked the proper medics are selected by division.  Here is an example I tried but I'm receiving an error:

```
  <%= f.label :houston %>
  <%= f.check_box :medic_ids, Medic.where(division: "Houston").map {|medic| medic.id} %>
  <%= f.label :dallas %>
  <%= f.check_box :medic_ids, Medic.where(division: "Dallas").map {|medic| medic.id} %>
```

The error I receive is:
`undefined method`merge' for #` when trying to do it this way.

I'm pretty sure this can be done, but after an hour of searching and trying different things I'm really no further than when I began.

I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction on this one.

In the meantime I will continue to Google and research Stack to see if someone else had a similar issue.

If my code and/or question is not concise or clear please let me know and I will edit.

**Update**

I'm realizing that `form_for` has limitations and I decided to switch to `form_tag` so that I could work with the params in the controller.  Here's what my code looks like now.

**mass_messaging_controller.rb**

```
  def create
    @mass_message = current_user.mass_messages.new
    @mass_message.subject = params[:subject]
    @mass_message.body = params[:body]
    @mass_message.medic_ids = params[:medic_ids]
    if @mass_message.save
      redirect_to mass_messaging_index_path, notice: "Your message has been queued for processing"
    else
      Rails.logger.info(@mass_message.errors.inspect)
      redirect_to mass_messaging_index_path, notice: "Your messasge failed to send"
    end
  end
```

**form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_tag('/mass_messaging', :method=>'post') do %>
 <p>
   Subject:<br />
   <%= text_field_tag "subject" %>
 </p>
 <p>
   Body:<br />
   <%= text_area_tag "body", "", :size=>"50x20" %>
 </p>
 <p>
   Divison: <br />
   <%= select_tag("medic_ids", options_for_select([['Houston', houston],
                 ['Dallas', dallas], ['Beumont', beaumont], ['Texoma', texoma]])) %>
 </p>
 <p>
   <%= submit_tag 'Submit' %>
 </p>
<% end %>
```

**mass_messaging_helper**

```
  def houston
    Medic.where(division: "Houston").map {|medic| medic.id}
  end

  def dallas
    Medic.where(division: "Dallas").map {|medic| medic.id}
  end

  def texoma
    Medic.where(division: "Texoma").map {|medic| medic.id}
  end

  def beaumont
    Medic.where(division: "Beaumont").map {|medic| medic.id}
  end
```

When I submit the form it passes the params properly as in this example but I raise an exception:  Here's an excerpt from the development.log

```
    Started POST "/mass_messaging" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-01-07 12:31:47 -0600
    Processing by MassMessagingController#create as HTML
      Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"MVfjUe901TYuXbwDgMWSzCsf9T7KI7UvzKkiYEKqpJU=", "subject"=>"", "body"=>"", "medic_ids"=>"[304, 635, 472, 349, 683, 702, 588, 486, 593, 492, 645, 536, 685, 686, 410, 417, 573, 564, 567, 678, 651, 474, 734, 408, 718]", "commit"=>"Submit"}
      User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
      Medic Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "medics".* FROM "medics" WHERE "medics"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 0]]
    Completed 404 Not Found in 6.0ms
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound - Couldn't find Medic with id=0:
```

So I feel like I'm making progress on this one and am on the right track, however I'm not sure what it's loading a medic with an ID of 0 as I don't see that in the param hash.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work finally by using my updated code and wrapping `params[:medic_ids] in`eval()` to evaluate the array inside of the string.  This along with my form_tag rewrite worked just how I needed it.